# Question about absolutely continuous distribution definition

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, radon-nikodym

So my book defines that a random variable $X$ has *absolutely continuous distribution* $F$, if it can be represented as $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x p(\mu)\,d\mu$ for some non-negative and integrable function $p$.

I was wondering if this definition is equivalent to asking for the pushforwards $P\circ X^{-1}$ to be absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Im kind of convinced that it has to be the Lebesgue measure since it completes the Borel measure but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, these are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you! This was bugging me for quite some time.

Comment: If these two notions were different, but both called "absolutely continuous", it would be bad.